# The algorithm to find if a line and a cube intersect in 3D space

Tags: algorithm, math, 3d

A line is defined by two (2) points A(Xa, Ya, Za), B(Xb, Yb, Zb)
A cube is defined by one (1) point C(Xc, Yc, Zc)

The cube is axis aligned, therefore it's points are defined at (Xc, Yc, Zc) -> (Xc + 1, Yc + 1, Zc + 1)

I've tried using the 2D algorithm for the same problem and scaling it up another dimension, i was not able to get it to work

Answer (score 1):

One of possible ways is to look at the cube as a part of space cut by 6 planes. Then just cut the line by those planes and see if anything left.

For convenience (to avoid considering line, ray and segment separately) we can cut the line preemptively by some large enough radius to make a segment from it.

```
bool DoesLineIntersectCube(Line line,Cube cube)
{
    projectedOrigin=Project(cube.Centre,line);
    segment=Segment(projectedOrigin-line.Direction*2,projectedorigin+line.Direction*2);
    for(axis:{0,1,2})
    {
        direction=(0,0,0);
        direction[axis]=1;
        segment=Cut(segment,MakePlane(cube.Centre+direction*0.5,direction);
        segment=Cut(segment,MakePlane(cube.Centre-direction*0.5,-direction);
    }
    return !segment.IsEmpty();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find separating plane:

- Consider a plane defined by the one endpoint of the line segment and one edge(2 end points) of the cube.
- Check which side of the plane the cube's remaining 6 vertices and line's another endpoint are.
- If the cube's 6 vertices are on the same side but only the line's endpoint is on the opposite side, line segment and cube do not intersect.

Check this for all possible plane.